# invalid file (bad magic number):how I could solve this when I execute JAR file not works using this java code?

Tags: java, jar

IM triying to run this code that use a event for execute a jar file but not works

How I could solve

IM triying to run this code that use a event for execute a jar file but not works

How I could solve

```
  JButton cn= new JButton("push me3");
  cn.setBounds( 0,0,295,20 );
  f.add(cn);  
  cn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)      {
  String title =hellopanelx40.getText();
  try{

  //All your IO Operations

  Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/example.jar");
  proc.waitFor();
  // Then retreive the process output
  InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
  InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream();

  byte b[]=new byte[in.available()];
  in.read(b,0,b.length);
  System.out.println(new String(b));

  byte c[]=new byte[err.available()];
  err.read(c,0,c.length);
  System.out.println(new String(c));

  }catch(Throwable t){
    t.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
  });
```

Please help me

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing (with a full error message and stack trace where appropriate), and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.

Comment: hi sorry my problem is that when I execute a jar file in terminal works ; but when I execute using java not works .

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command that works, the exact command that doesn't, and the exact error (with full stack trace) you get.

Comment: all code compile but when I execute my jar file not works ; but in terminal works IM triying to change the permission of my JAR  file and not works

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact command that works, the exact command that doesn't, and the exact error (with full stack trace) you get.

Comment: this command compile perfectly my problem is that I dont understand because I cant execute this jar in java

Comment: I have asked twice for you to [edit] your question with certain information.  You have yet to provide this information, and thus we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In exec(), try changing "java -jar /home/example.jar"